# Upload Image taken from android phone

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that will upload image which is taken from android phone. In my current code one of my if condition becomes true that return 0 and due to which my function stop working and it also does not upload image to server.

Here is my code

```
public class Camera extends Activity {
ImageView ivUserImage;
Button bUpload;
Intent i;
int CameraResult = 0;
Bitmap bmp;

int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
    bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
    openCamera();
}

private void openCamera() {
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        //Log.e("Image: ", data.toString());
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ivUserImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        bUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Camera.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    //tv.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                             });
                         int response= uploadFile(bmp.toString());
                         //Log.e("Response: ", response);
                         System.out.println("RES : " + response);
                        }
                      }).start();
                }
        });
    }
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String upLoadServerUri = "http://www.example.info/androidfileupload/index.php";
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sourceFileUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }

    try { 
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

         // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
             dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if(serverResponseCode == 200){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     //tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                     Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            });
        }    

        //close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
    return serverResponseCode;
}

}
```

In my uploadFile() method this condition becomes true `if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
            return 0;
        }`.

How can I solve this problem the upload image which is taken from camera?

**Update**

Here is my logcat

```
06-10 16:30:08.595: D/CLIPBOARD(27966): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-10 16:30:10.305: D/PhoneWindow(27966): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4053eca0 has no id.
06-10 16:30:10.980: D/CLIPBOARD(27966): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
06-10 16:30:11.015: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27966): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-10 16:32:18.005: D/PhoneWindow(27966): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4053eca0 has no id.
06-10 16:32:38.890: D/dalvikvm(27966): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 101K, 46% free 3097K/5639K, external 879K/1025K, paused 37ms
06-10 16:37:19.145: D/PhoneWindow(27966): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4053eca0 has no id.
06-10 16:39:01.805: E/uploadFile(27966): Source File Does not exist
06-10 16:39:01.805: I/System.out(27966): RES : 0
06-10 16:39:09.185: D/PhoneWindow(27966): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4053eca0 has no id.
06-10 16:39:09.475: D/CLIPBOARD(27966): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve this problem the upload image which is taken from
>   camera?

Following Snippet will help you.

```
public void UploadImage(Bitmap bm) throws Exception {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://www.example.info/androidfileupload/index.php");
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", bab);
            reqEntity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody("sfsdfsdf"));
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            System.out.println("Response: " + s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception here
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you send bitmap string via this line

int response= uploadFile(bmp.toString());

Here you send Bitmap String. Do not send path of the images. so this (!sourceFile.isFile()) line do not found any file path.

I think that make a problem.

you debug you code that help you to find problem.

Thanks

Comment: after debuging i get this android.graphics.Bitmap@4058a368 in sourceFileUri

Comment: It is not file url. if you want to check file exist or not then  you need to save it in phone memory or sdcard, after taking photo. Better to upload photo without save.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I want. How can I upload image without saving to the phone? I will appreciate any code sample that you can provide.